# jquery cross site access variable

Tags: jquery, permission-denied, cross-site

I have two different application. One for blog list page another one for blog details page. Here blog details page will open in popup using **window.open** while clicking on blog name. This blog details coming from another server. I have to access blog list page declared client side variable in blog popup page. I tried below example but it's returned permission denied error. Please help me, i need to fix this issue.

Example: First Domain **http://example.blog.com/bloglist.php**

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var blogType = "test";
    $("body").on("click", "a.blogdetails", function () {
        var getId = $("this").attr('id');
        openSeperateWindow = window.open("http://example.bloglist.com?id="+getId);        
    });
</script>

Example: Second Domain
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var getParentWindow = window.opener;
    console.log(getParentWindow.blogType ); // It's returning permission denied to access 'blogType'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relatively new [.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between cross-domain sites with javascript. [Browser support is pretty decent with modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage).

There are quite good examples you can find with googling. MDN Documentation is a good place to start.

- [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
- [`MessageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent)